# How to change, customize, Mongoose default _id property?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema:

```js
const { ObjectId } = Schema.Types

const Account = new Schema({
    name:           { type: String, required: true },
    accountId:      { type: String, required: true },
    piracicaba:     [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Piracicaba'}]
})
```

I know that by default MongoDB creates an `_id` property, but I would like to make `accountId` my default ID instead. Also, I would like to change that default generated string to a custom one.

How could I do that?

I have tried to change the `accountId` type to `ObjectId`:

```js
const { ObjectId } = Schema.Types

const Account = new Schema({
    name:           { type: String, required: true },
    accountId:      { type: ObjectId },
    piracicaba:     [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Piracicaba'}]
})
```

But then when I try to store my customized ID mongoose throws `BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer`.

My customized ID is from Oracle Cloud Account and it looks like this: `ocid1.test.oc1..<unique_ID>EXAMPLE-compartmentId-Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include an `_id` field in your schema definition, when you insert a document you must supply it with your own manually generated `_id`. If you don't, the document will not get inserted.

Alternatively, if you do not include an `_id` field in your schema definition, Mongoose will create this for you automatically, when the document is inserted, and it will be of type `ObjectId` (which is the default way that MongoDB sets the `_id` field on documents).

Comment: SELOCO CACHOEIRA, FUNCIONOU LINDAMENTE!